# Laravel - Database store function not working

Tags: php, laravel, crud

I am having trouble when inputting data and figuring out why my data is not being stored into the database. I have tried to use the resources route and my custom route code, but it seems still nothing works. Clicking submit just seems to refresh the page with no errors to show

And here is my form :

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">                            
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark primary justify-content-between">
            <div class="navbar-brand text-dark">Create a Story</div>
        </nav>
        <hr class="mt-3">   
        <form action="{{route('story.store')}}" method="post">
            @csrf
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col col-lg-6">
                    <div class="form-group my-3">
                        <label for="title">Title</label><br>
                        <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="w-100 form-control{{ $errors->has('title') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" value="{{ old('title') }}" required>
                        @if ($errors->has('title'))
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert"><strong>{{ $errors->first('title') }}</strong></span>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col col-lg-6">
                    <div class="form-group my-3">
                        <label for="category">Category</label><br>
                        <select name="category" id="category" class="w-100 form-control{{ $errors->has('category') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" value="{{ old('category') }}" required>
                            <option value="Active" selected>Select Category</option>
                            @foreach ($category as $item)
                                <option value="{{$item->id}}">{{$item->nama}}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                        @if ($errors->has('category'))
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert"><strong>{{ $errors->first('category') }}</strong></span>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col col-lg-6">
                    <div class="form-group my-3">
                        <label for="thumbnail">Story Thumbnail <span class="text-muted">(Recomended size is 650 x 350 pixel)</span></label><br>
                        <input type="file" name="thumbnail" id="thumbnail">
                        @if ($errors->has('thumbnail'))
                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert"><strong>{{ $errors->first('thumbnail') }}</strong></span>
                        @endif                            
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col col-lg-12">                                
                    <div class="form-group mt-4">
                        <textarea id="text-content"  name="content" class="w-100 form-control{{$errors->has('content') ? ' is-invalid' : ''}}" id="content" rows="3" value="{{old('content')}}"></textarea>
                        @if ($errors->has('content'))
                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert"><strong>{{ $errors->first('content') }}</strong></span>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer pb-0">
                <div class="float-right">                        
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-md">Publish Story</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>                               
    </div>
</div>
```

The store function in controller :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{                
    $user = Auth::user();
    $request->validate([
        'title' => 'required|string',
        'category' => 'required',
        'thumbnail' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',            
        'content' => 'required',
    ]);

    $thumbnailName = time().'.'.request()->thumbnail->getClientOriginalExtension();                

    $post = new Post;
    $post->title = request('title');
    $post->category_id = request('category');
    $post->thumbnail = request('thumbnail');
    $post->content = request('content');
    $post->title = request('title');
    $post->date = date('d-m-Y');
    $post->author_id = $user->id;
    $post->save();

    $request->thumbnail->move(asset('storage/uploads'), $thumbnailName);
    return redirect('me/stories')->with('Succes', 'Story has been published')->with('thumbnail', $thumbnailName);                    
}
```

And this is the routes:

```
Route::get('me/stories', 'PostController@index')->name('story');
Route::get('me/stories/create', 'PostController@create')->name('story.create');
Route::post('me/stories/store', 'PostController@store')->name('story.store');
Route::post('ck/image_upload', 'PostController@imageUpload')->name('ck.upload');
```

I'm not getting any error messages at all, it's just that the submission button does nothing. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's a silly question, but are your post fields defined as `fillable` in your `Post` mode? Also, give us the `php artisan route:list` output in your question.

Comment: @zlatan there is no mass assignment there unfortunately, good idea though

Comment: `$post->category_id = request('category');` change to `$post->category_id = $request->category;` change also other request( );

Comment: I got an error when trying $request('something'), try what @Zar Ni Ko Ko suggested

Comment: your form isn't setup to handle files

Comment: Have you checked `fillable or guarded` in `Post` model ?

Comment: as @lagbox noticed, you're missing the attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on your form tag to be able to upload a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Clicking submit just seems to refresh the page with no errors to show

Your Validator is doing a return to last page with the errors.

Add this snippet of code to your blade

```html
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Also, inspect the page before submitting and go to the network tab (check preserve log at the top) and proceed with the submission, you will get more details of what happened.

Comment: this should be what is happening, the OP's form isn't setup to handle files at the least